# How to solve the error when building the android kernel?

Tags: android, linux, build, linux-kernel, android-kernel

make -j5

```
drivers/gpu/mali400/Kconfig:12:error: recursive dependency detected!
drivers/gpu/mali400/Kconfig:12: choice <choice> contains symbol MALI400
drivers/gpu/mali400/r4p0/Kconfig:1: symbol MALI400 depends on <choice>
```

---

How can I solve this problem?

Here is the content of Kconfig:

```
menuconfig MALI400
    tristate "Mali-300/400/450 support"
    depends on ARM
    default y
    ---help---
    This enables support for the ARM Mali-300, Mali-400, and Mali-450
    GPUs.

    To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the module will be
    called mali.

choice
    depends on MALI400
    prompt "Select MALI VER"
    default MALI_VER_R4P0
    config MALI_VER_R4P0
      bool "Mali400 Version R4P0"
      help
        Choose this option to select DDK version.

if MALI_VER_R4P0
source "drivers/gpu/mali400/r4p0/Kconfig"
endif

endchoice
```

Does it need to be corrected somehow? How?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you share a link to the particular kernel sources or the contents of `drivers/gpu/mali400/r4p0/Kconfig`